# XPATH queries work different results on servers with the same configuration

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xalan

I have 2 windows servers running the same Java version.
I have java application which uses the same version of xalan to open XML document and extracts text from the node with query:

```
//*[local-name()='article']/*[local-name()='p' and @prism:class='News']/text()
```

from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psv
    xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/3.0/">
    <content>
        <article>
            <p id="1" prism:class="News">NEWSLETTER HEAD</p>
        </article>
    </content>
</psv>
```

On one server it extracts text correctly, on another server it can not find the node. What else should I check except xalan and java verisons?
Thank you!

Comment: Is it actually opening the document on the second sever? If not, could be a file system security issue.

Comment: How are you executing the XPath expression?

Comment: Yes, the document opens on both servers correctly and query gets executed without errors, but one returns result, another does not.

Comment: The method I'm using is this one: XPathAPI.selectNodeList(pContextNode, psXPath)